# docker-compose up not starting service

Tags: docker

I am trying to get a simple docker-compose file working on windows.

```
version: "2"

volumes:
  db_data: {}

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test123
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql/data
```

I need to persist the db data. I've created the directory db_data and I found this solution from a github issue: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/69. I had previously been using mysql 5.6. I'm simply running

```
docker-compose up -d
```

when I check

```
docker ps
```

I do not get any running processes. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I've added the output from running the command below:

```
PS D:\test-exercise> docker-compose up -d
Starting test-exercise_db_1 ... done
```

Comment: What output do you get if you run without the -d?

Comment: remove the volumes definition, then try `- ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql`, please show the error messages

Comment: I mean, run `docker-compose up` (without the `-d`) and give us the output.

Comment: What error does it show in  `docker ps -a` output? Are you sure the container was not running?

Comment: There isn't an error `docker ps` doesn't show any containers running.